# Using ternary for if else

Tags: ios, swift, ternary-operator

I’m having this if-else condition..

```
if UIDevice.current.iPad {
    if APIClient.shared.whiteLabel == .gld_default || APIClient.shared.whiteLabel == .abc {
        theImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    } else {
        theImage.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    }
} else {
    theImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
}
```

How can I use a ternary operator instead of this if-else condition..

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41524938/result-values-in-expression-have-mismatching-types-and-bool) link..but it didn’t help

Comment: Using a ternary on it "long if" (a lot of char) (and there is two ifs) might make it less readable. But the middle one is `theImage.contentMode = (APIClient.shared.whiteLabel == .gld_default || APIClient.shared.whiteLabel == .abc) ? . scaleAspectFill : . scaleToFill`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the inside if:

```
if APIClient.shared.whiteLabel == .gld_default || APIClient.shared.whiteLabel == .abc {
   theImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
} else {
   theImage.contentMode = .scaleToFill
}
```

Gives:

```
theImage.contentMode = (APIClient.shared.whiteLabel == .gld_default || APIClient.shared.whiteLabel == .abc) ? . scaleAspectFill : . scaleToFill
```

Now, if we do the top level if:

```
theImage.contentMode = UIDevice.current.iPad ? insideIf : . scaleAspectFill
```

In full code:

```
theImage.contentMode = UIDevice.current.iPad ? (APIClient.shared.whiteLabel == .gld_default || APIClient.shared.whiteLabel == .abc) ? . scaleAspectFill 
                                                                                                                                    : . scaleToFill 
                                             : . scaleAspectFill
```

That's not really redable.

But

```
if UIDevice.current.iPad {
    if APIClient.shared.whiteLabel == .gld_default || APIClient.shared.whiteLabel == .abc {
        theImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    } else {
        theImage.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    }
} else {
    theImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
}
```

Might be transformed into:

```
if UIDevice.current.iPad && !(APIClient.shared.whiteLabel == .gld_default || APIClient.shared.whiteLabel == .abc) {
    theImage.contentMode = .scaleToFill
} else {
    theImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
}
```

That's shorter, but might be harder to read.

With ternary if:

```
theImage.contentMode = UIDevice.current.iPad && !(APIClient.shared.whiteLabel == .gld_default || APIClient.shared.whiteLabel == .abc) ? . scaleToFill : . scaleAspectFill
```

In my opinion? Keep your version (or maybe the version where I use only one if/else). Compiler will optimise nevertheless, and it's easier to fix/modify it two months later if you can grasp why and what it does quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can break down it in to

```
theImage.contentMode = APIClient.shared.whiteLabel == .gld_default || APIClient.shared.whiteLabel == .abc ? .scaleAspectFill : .scaleToFill
```